# IF ELSE string comparison from curl

Tags: curl, string, variable, test

When I do:

```
URL_CURL_CHECK="https://github.com/"
VAR_A=$(curl -Is --head "$URL_CURL_CHECK" | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
VAR_B="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

echo
if [ "$VAR_A" != "$VAR_B" ]; then
    echo "Not equal ..."
else [ "$VAR_A" = "$VAR_B" ]
    echo "It's a match"
fi

echo
echo "Validate VARs: "
echo "$VAR_A"
echo "$VAR_B"
```

Here is the output:

```
Not equal ...

Validate VARs:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I don't understand why when I compare VAR_A with VAR_B it's always "Not equal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in `$VAR_A` has a trailing `\r` (carriage return) at the end, which makes the string comparison fail. It will have a carriage return since this is an HTTP header, and the end-of-line marker in HTTP headers are specified in [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) as `\r\n`.

One way to fix this:

```
VAR_A=$(curl -Is --head "$URL_CURL_CHECK" | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" | tr -d '\r')
```

`tr -d '\r'` will remove all carriage returns.

Another alternative is to get `grep` to only return the matched text (which will be exactly the string `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`):

```
VAR_A=$(curl -Is --head "$URL_CURL_CHECK" | grep -o "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
```

You might in any case want to use `-F` with `grep` here as the string is a fixed string rather than a regular expression:

```
VAR_A=$(curl -Is --head "$URL_CURL_CHECK" | grep -F -o "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
```

Your script also uses `else` with a condition. Either use *just* `else` or use `elif` with a condition. In this case, just remove the condition.

Comment: Just saw your edits. Even better :)